# Run filter in each row dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to manage a dynamic set of data over the course of several steps, and at each step I need to remove a specific value from each row, and shift the remaining values to the left to fill in any blanks.

I know I can use

```
=arrayformula(if(range=value, "", range))
```

to remove the specific value, but I've only been able to find

```
=filter(row, row<>"")
```

to fill in the blanks, but since the number of rows changes, this isn't going to work.

Edit:

I want to turn something like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data A1 | Data B1 | Data C1 |
| Data A2 | Data B2 | Data C2 |
| Data A3 | Data B3 | Data C3 |
| Data A4 | Data B4 | Data C4 |
| etc | etc | etc |

to this

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data A1 | Data C1 |  |
| Data A2 | Data B2 | Data C2 |
| Data B3 | Data C3 |  |
| Data C4 |  |  |
| etc | etc | etc |

Since I only know how many columns there are, I can only pre-set the formula to filter each column, which moves data vertically. I want to move it horizontally, but where the number of rows is variable, I can't manually pre-set each row to use filter.

Comment: `FILTER()`, itself is a dynamic spill array formula. What do you mean by dynamically? Always post sample data as well as expected result.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: @Harun24hr ```FILTER()``` only works on a single row/column, so I need some way to apply it to any row that has data without the formula having been manually entered in for each row beforehand.

Comment: Then use `MMULT()` with `FILTER()` function.

Comment: Could you explain? From what I can find, ```MMULT()``` is a math function, which doesn't seem applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: applying FILTER() in combination with BYROW(). Because Google's BYROW() is unfortunately limited to a single value return from it's LAMBDA(), we have to rely on the old ARRAYFORMULA/JOIN/SPLIT trick.

```
=arrayformula(
   split(
     byrow(A1:C4, 
           lambda(row,
                  ifna(
                    join(",",
                         filter(row, row<>"A")),
                    ""))),
     ","))
```

[image]

Comment: `as opposed to Excel's` Excel supports multi value return?

Comment: Hmm you're right, I double-checked and Excel's BYROW() also requires the function to return a scalar.

Comment: Thanks! Now I need to dissect it because there's functions I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @ttarchala the only issue is that, below the last cell in the first column, I get | ,,,, |  I'm posting on mobile, it doesn't want to cooperate with formatting

Comment: Yes, the formula does not contain any guards/error checks against applying it to empty rows, or applying it to rows that contain only the value to be filtered out. They are quite trivial to apply with a couple of IF()'s or IFERROR()s. Let us know if you need help with that too.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (23-Jan-2023), it appears that Google has updated the BYROW/BYCOL functions to allow the return of an array result per row/column, so the answer to the OPs question could now simply be `=byrow(range,lambda(row,filter(row,row<>"")))`.

I have not seen this documented anywhere, and the help pages for the BYROW & BYCOL functions still state that only a single value per row/column is allowed.

Slightly off-topic, but I can also confirm that you can pass the individual row/columns from a BYROW/BYCOL into the other LHFs as well (e.g. a SCAN within a BYROW to give a row-wise running total, etc.)